# ClassLoader: Treating a class as a resource - safe or implementation detail?

Tags: java, classloader

For my use case, I want to transfer a class (not an object, the actual class file) over a Socket connection, then load that class on the receiving end.

The class is included normally in the project (on the sending end), so its *somewhere* on the class path.

I have all the code working, but to actually *get* the class file from the classpath, I had to resort to somewhat oddly mistreating the class as a resource (Code stripped down to essential part):

```
public class ClassTransport {

    public byte[] data;
    public String qualifiedName;

    public static ClassTransport create(Class<?> theClass) throws Exception {
        ClassTransport result = new ClassTransport();
        result.qualifiedName = theClass.getName();
        // brute force derive the class file name
        String classResourceName = theClass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";             

        ClassLoader cl = theClass.getClassLoader();
        try (InputStream in = cl.getResourceAsStream(classResourceName)) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) >= 0) {
                out.write(b);
            }
            out.close();
            result.data = out.toByteArray();
        }
        return result;      
    }

}
```

This works, but is it actually *safe* to do this or does it violate any specifications - specifically what are the possibilites where this may *fail* to retrieve the class in future JRE releases or on a specific platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it's probably fine.

Longer answer: it's not guaranteed to be fine, because nothing in the JLS guarantees that classes in packages are organized as files in directories.

The pertinent section of the JLS is [7.2. Host Support for Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.2):

> In simple implementations of the Java SE platform, packages and compilation units may be stored in a local file system. Other implementations may store them using a distributed file system or some form of database.
>
> If a host system stores packages and compilation units in a database, then the database must not impose the optional restrictions (§7.6) on compilation units permissible in file-based implementations.

The gist is that the classpath, in theory, might be in something like a database instead of a filesystem. So although your approach doesn't **violate** any specifications, it also isn't **supported** by any specification. I can't find any system where this is the case though, so you're *probably* okay assuming a file system in most cases.

This has also been discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454208/why-does-java-want-package-names-defined) StackOverflow question.